# sending emails from ansible, mail is not a valid attriubute for a Play

Tags: ansible

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.infinitypp.com/ansible/email-notifications-with-examples

from it I have constructed the following playbook called test.yml containing the following code:

```
---
  - name: sending an email
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
     - name: send email
       local_action: mail
   subject="ansible sent this"
       to="my name <myemail.example.com>"
       body="this is the body"
```

however I get this error:

```
ERROR! 'mail' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/path/test.yml': line 1, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Send email
  ^ here
```

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Your yaml is not correct](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). More specifically you have indentation problems.
2. You are wrongly mixing old style (parameters with "=" in a string) and current style (full yaml) module declaration. I strongly suggest your stop using old style declarations and use yaml only syntax. You will save time and energy.
3. The first two points alone probably explain the error your are getting although I get a totally different one when trying to run your code. For the future, you should always run your playbooks through [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) and correct the reported errors prior to searching implementation problems.
4. You are using `local_action` while your play is targeting localhost which is redundant. This is not an error but just adds to the confusion. If you really need localhost delegation (because you intent to target other hosts in your play while still sending mails from the ansible controler), have a look at the [`delegate_to`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) option which produces much more readable tasks IMO (i.e. `delegate_to: localhost`)

Here is a corrected playbook which should get you on track. I kept the localhost delegation for the example. You just have to remove the line if you will not use it.

```
---
- name: sending an email
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: send email
      mail:
        subject: "ansible sent this"
        to: "my name <myemail.example.com>"
        body: "this is the body"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml is malformed, the correct playbook is:

```
---
  - name: sending an email
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
     - name: send email
       local_action:
          module: mail
          subject: "ansible sent this"
          to: "my name <myemail.example.com>"
          body: "this is the body"
```

When using `local_action`, you should specify the module using the key `module`. Also, you should use `:` for key/value pairs, not `=`.

Comment: ...and you should generally prefer `delegate_to: localhost` over `local_action`, because it does not require the use of the `module:` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are not including some parameters in the mail module. I was receiving the same error as you.

What seemed to fix my issue was changing the port I had set in the YAML. The previous port was 465. This was one of the options offered when trying to connection to Office 365. I changed my port to 587.

Below is the YAML file that works for me.

```yaml
- name: Sending an email
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: send email
      mail:
        host: smtp.office365.com
        port: 587
        username: <my_email_address>
        password: <my_password>
        to: <my_email_address>
        from: <my_email_address>
        subject: Test Email
        body: 'This is a test email to verify that E-mails can get sent from ansible. if this is received then the send was a success :) !'
```